# Every object accessed returns a new object

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm working on an e-commerce app and I'm having a hard time to create a singleton object which I can use as the shopping cart of my app.

First, I created a Service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Item} from '../models/item';

@Injectable()
export class CartService {

    private items: Item[];

    constructor() {
      this.items = [];
    }

    public addToCart(item: Item): string {
       ...
    }

    public getItems(): Item[] {
      return this.items;
    }
}
```

then in my app.module.ts:

```
import { CartService } from '../services/cart.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     MyApp,
     ...
  ],
  imports: [
     ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    CartService
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now I want to have the cartService.getItems as a singleton array of items, so I do:

```
 @IonicPage({
   name: 'destaques-page'
 })
 @Component({
   selector: 'page-destaques',
   templateUrl: 'destaques.html'
 })
 export class DestaquesPage {
     ...

     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, db: AngularFireDatabase, private cart: CartService) {
         ...

         console.log(this.cart.getItems.length);
     }
     ...
  }
```

in every page I want to access that object, but in each one I get a brand new object which means I can't have all the different items I've added already.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Ideally it should not, did you put console log in constructor and see how many times its getting called ?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the class decorator for the `DestaquesPage` class/component? I would like to see for a fact that you *do not* have a `providers` section with the `CartService` in there, too.

Comment: @Skeptor which constructor do you want me to put the log in? The DestaquesPage one or the app.component.ts one?

Comment: @R.Richards done

Comment: Might i suggest you use something like `Redux` for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the page is not loaded completely while redirecting. As if the page is loaded again the service gets destroyed from the memory and the items are initialized to [] again.

Ideally you should be using localStorage, with your service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Item} from '../models/item';

@Injectable()
export class CartService {

private items: Item[];

constructor() {
  try {
    this.items = JSON.parse(localStorage.get("mycart")) as Item[];
  } catch(err) {
    this.items = [];
  }
}

public addToCart(item: Item): string {
   this.items.push(item);
   localStorage.setItem("mycart", JSON.stringify(this.items));
}

public getItems(): Item[] {
  return this.items;
}
}
```

I hope this would help the cause